# How to select from vim command line?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find a pattern and delete the block.

To delete the block I do `V$%x` manually.

V - Row select, $ - Move to end of line (there is a { end of line), % - Move to matching }, x - remove the block

I was wondering is there a way to automate it. There is global command `:g` but I don't know how to select text in command mode.

Comment: Have you tried `da{`?

Comment: That again works in normal mode, not in command line mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for record, found solution

EDIT:

`:g/pattern/norm! V$%x`

Comment: You can leave out the exe: `:g/pattern/norm! V$%d`.

Comment: `V$` ? what role does `$` play here? `V` is already line-wise selection. and you better make examples, since I cannot get what you want to do with this command. it has different problems... well it depends what you want to achieve and how do your lines look like.

Comment: @Kent: suppose you have your cursor in first character and there is a function `void func(int a, int b) {` `%` will move you to `)` next to b, not to `}` at the end of function

Comment: ok@ChakradarRaju I get what you want. you want to remove the whole `{...}` block with function/method signature. then you need write your `pattern` carefully..

Answer (score 0):

When you activate visual mode by pressing `v` you can select:

```
aw  a word (with white space)           
iw  inner word                  
aW  a WORD (with white space)           
iW  inner WORD                  
as  a sentence (with white space)           
is  inner sentence                  
ap  a paragraph (with white space)          
ip  inner paragraph                 
ab  a () block (with parenthesis)           
ib  inner () block                  
aB  a {} block (with braces)            
iB  inner {} block                  
a<  a <> block (with <>)                
i<  inner <> block                  
a[  a [] block (with [])                
i[  inner [] block
```

hope that helps

Comment: To automate, I wanted to select text from command mode not visual mode.